# Pytest: use parametrize output of fixture as class instance name in test

Tags: python, pytest

I have a problem with using data provided by `pytest_generate_tests`. The point is that data is provided as tuple of string values, and further in tests i need one of them to be used as name of the tested class, and i can't find solution how to initialize class with this str value as it's name

Here is a simple class for tests:

```
class Grade(Enum):
    TRAINEE = 1
    JUNIOR = 2
    MIDDLE = 5
    SENIOR = 10

class Employee(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, name, surname, grade: Grade):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        base = 300
        self.salary = int(base * grade.value)

class QAEngineer(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, surname, salary):
        super().__init__(name, surname, salary)
```

and a simple test to check if instances are initialized correctly. 
For this test fixture with `pytest_generate_tests` method is written. Fixture uses data from simple input txt file in the form:

```
QAEngineer, Mary, Mills, SENIOR
```

and create from it `param_list` in the following way:

```
[['QAEngineer', ('Mary', 'Mills', 'SENIOR')]]
```

and return as:

```
metafunc.parametrize("emplopyee_class, employee_parameters", tuple(params_list2))
```

so employee_class  = QAEngineer, employee_parameters = ('Mary', 'Mills', 'SENIOR')

then i need to provide `emplopyee_class, employee_parameters` values in my test, and here the problem is - since `emplopyee_class` is str, i can't use it as class name when create QAEngineer instance for test, so i need to hardcode it, i.e.:

```
def test_emp_append_file(emplopyee_class, employee_parameters):
    grade = Grade.__getattr__(employee_parameters[2])
    employee = QAEngineer(employee_parameters[0], employee_parameters[1], grade)
    assert employee.name == employee_parameters[0]
    assert employee.surname == employee_parameters[1]
```

How can i change `emplopyee_class`type and to what type to make it possible to use as a class name, so to wrote something like this instead:

```
employee = emplopyee_class(employee_parameters[0], employee_parameters[1], grade)
```

?

Comment: Why not use `QAEngineer` class object instead of class name in `param_list`?

Comment: @hoefling there are few more similar classes, and they all should be given in input file in the way given above. Or you meant read `QAEngineer ` from file and then pass it to `param_list` not as simple str value, but as class object?Have no ideas how to do it either

Comment: Oh, somehow I overlooked the input data reading from text file. However, you can invoke the `importlib` machinery for dynamic importing of classes, given their names; you would just need to store the qualified class name (like `pkg.module.QAEngineer` - same as you use to import the class in code). If you need a working example, complete your code to a [mcve] so I can run it  from my machine.

Comment: @hoefling, will it be ok?
.py file with classes, fixture and simple test - https://pastebin.com/HhqFkQrH
input_data.txt with test data for test - https://pastebin.com/ACatrd1w

Comment: If you want to keep the tested code in the same file as the tests, then you can simply take the class from `globals()`: change `params_list1.append([vals[0])` to `params_list1.append(globals()[vals[0]])` and your example should work already.

Comment: however, in the real setup, you probably keep the tested code apart from the tests, then use qualified names for classes in the `input_data.txt` (`pkg.mod.QAEngineer` etc) and use e.g. `pydoc.locate` to look up the class: ìmport pydoc.locate` and change `params_list1.append([vals[0])` to `params_list1.append(pydoc.locate(vals[0]))`. Of course, `pydoc` doesn't have a public API, but we're talking about test code here.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `importlib`, although it will be bit more verbose: `import importlib`, then `(modname, clsname) = vals[0].rsplit('.', 1)`. now you can import the module dynamically: `module = importlib.import_module(modname)`, get the class: `cls = getattr(module, clsname)` and append it instead of class name: `params_list1.append(cls)`.